# plotting in python with congruent x-values

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Goal: Get two different names on the same graph. Make sure that the years line up. Note, not the file has some years twice (when a name has been given to both girl & boy), in that case add the values for all split years per name.

Current status: one name is working. Two names changes the index to the row number instead of the year number.

Y: 'prop' == the proportion of the name (regardless of sex) to all names given that year to newborns.

X: 'year' == the year of the birth certificate

https://raw2.github.com/hadley/data-baby-names/master/baby-names.csv

has the csv

CODE:

```
import pandas
import pylab
import matplotlib
from pandas import *
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import *

names = read_csv(r'C:\Users\joe\Documents\Python\baby-names2.csv')


import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



resultAry = names[names.name.isin(['Joseph', 'Nancy'])].set_index(['year','name'])['prop']

print (resultAry.head())
print ('***************')
resultAry = resultAry.groupby(level='name')
print (resultAry.head())
resultAry = resultAry.plot()




plt.show()
```

Thanks, everyone.

[image: Output Plot]

The graphs do not line up since there are years with girls named 'Joseph' and boys names 'Nancy'.

============UPDATE============== 2/13/2014

```
In [12]:

import pandas
import pylab
import matplotlib
from pandas import *
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import *

names = read_csv(r'C:\Users\joe\Documents\Python\baby-names2.csv')
print (names.head())

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

userNames = ['Joseph', 'Nancy']

resultAry = names[names.name.isin(userNames)].set_index(['year','name','sex'])['prop']
resultAry = resultAry.groupby(level='name')
print (resultAry.head())
print ('***************')
resultAry = resultAry.groupby(level='year')
print (resultAry)
#resultAry = resultAry.plot()

   year     name      prop  sex soundex
0  1880     John  0.081541  boy    J500
1  1880  William  0.080511  boy    W450
2  1880    James  0.050057  boy    J520
3  1880  Charles  0.045167  boy    C642
4  1880   George  0.043292  boy    G620
name    year  name    sex
Joseph  1880  Joseph  boy    0.022229
        1881  Joseph  boy    0.022679
        1882  Joseph  boy    0.021879
        1883  Joseph  boy    0.022367
        1884  Joseph  boy    0.022062
Nancy   1889  Nancy   boy    0.000059
        1933  Nancy   boy    0.000044
        1934  Nancy   boy    0.000044
        1935  Nancy   boy    0.000042
        1936  Nancy   boy    0.000059
dtype: float64
***************
name
Joseph    [(1880, [0.022229, 0.000102]), (1881, [0.02267...
Nancy     [(1880, [0.004211]), (1881, [0.004339]), (1882...
dtype: object
```

Next I got them to add the two values but I am still having a formatting error.
    arr = list(resultAry['Joseph'])

```
for i, (year, numbers) in enumerate(arr):
    arr[i][1][:] = [ sum(numbers) ]
print (arr)

[(1880, year  name    sex 
1880  Joseph  boy     0.022331
              girl    0.022331
Name: Joseph, dtype: float64), (1881, year...
```

Any help advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're using the Census baby names dataset? The one used in [Wes McKinney's book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do)? In the future it's a good idea to include a sample from your dataset so that others can reproduce your work.

I've just got 2006 - 2010 read into a DataFrame, like this.

```
In [75]: df.head()
Out[75]: 
       name sex    num  year
0     Emily   F  21365  2006
1      Emma   F  19092  2006
2   Madison   F  18599  2006
3  Isabella   F  18200  2006
4       Ava   F  16925  2006
```

Added in `prop` as defined above:

```
In [26]: df['prop'] = df.groupby('year')['num'].transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())


In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
         name sex    num  year      prop
0       Emily   F  21365  2006  0.005413
1        Emma   F  19092  2006  0.004837
2     Madison   F  18599  2006  0.004713
3    Isabella   F  18200  2006  0.004611
4         Ava   F  16925  2006  0.004288
5     Abigail   F  15615  2006  0.003956
```

I'd suggest a different approach to get the counts by name and year. I think it will make plotting easier. Instead of making two dataframes, one for each name, do it at the same time.

```
In [48]: df.query('name in ["Joeseph", "Nancy"]')
Out[48]: 
           name sex   num  year      prop
323       Nancy   F  1014  2006  0.000257
23206   Joeseph   M    34  2006  0.000009
34401     Nancy   F   896  2007  0.000225
57551   Joeseph   M    39  2007  0.000010
69300     Nancy   F   853  2008  0.000218
92066   Joeseph   M    45  2008  0.000011
104394    Nancy   F   663  2009  0.000174
127335  Joeseph   M    34  2009  0.000009
139050    Nancy   F   565  2010  0.000154
161863  Joeseph   M    29  2010  0.000008

[10 rows x 5 columns]
```

Prior to pandas .13 you can use `df[df.name.isin(['Joeseph', 'Nancy'])]`

Since you already have `prop` calculated, we don't need any further `groupby`s (this is a bit simpler than what I had before):

```
In [42]: s = df.query('name in ["Joeseph", "Nancy"]').set_index(['year', 'name'])['prop']

In [46]: ax = s.unstack().plot()
```

[image]

With this method you shouldn't have to worry about aligning the x-values. It's already done for you.

Comment: I am getting an error since there are duplicate entries of the index.

Comment: Apparently, Nancy used to be a boys name so some years (like 1889) it will show up twice. You'll need to decide how you want to handle those.

Comment: I want to add them. that was why I originally wanted to combine all of the values with the same index value.

Comment: OK. So once you have `s = df.query('name in ["Joeseph", "Nancy"]').set_index(['year', 'name'])['prop']`, do a `s = s.groupby(level='name').sum()`. That should give you what you want. Then you can `s.unstack().plot()`