# Adding numbers within object

Tags: python, arrays, object, matplotlib

I am trying to add the numbers that are paired with particular years, then graph the results on the same plot.

The array is formatted this way:

```
[(year, [one or two nums]),(year, [one or two nums]),(year, [one or two nums]),... ]
```

Here is the code the data can be found at: https://raw2.github.com/hadley/data-baby-names/master/baby-names.csv

```
import pandas
import pylab
import matplotlib
from pandas import *
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import *

names = read_csv(r'C:\Users\joe\Documents\Python\baby-names2.csv')
print (names.head())

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



resultAry = names[names.name.isin(['Joseph', 'Nancy'])].set_index(['year','name','sex'])['prop']
resultAry = resultAry.groupby(level='name')
print (resultAry.head())
print ('***************')
resultAry = resultAry.groupby(level='year')
print (resultAry)
#resultAry = resultAry.plot()

name
Joseph    [(1880, [0.022209, 0.000102]), (1881, [0.02267...
Nancy     [(1880, [0.004211]), (1881, [0.004339]), (1882...
dtype: object
```

Ideally the array would list the the year and the sum of the two proportions that are listed with it.

quasi code

```
[(year1,[prop1 + prop2(if exists)]),(year2,[prop1 + prop2(if exists)])...]
```

Out would be different in the first embedded list
    name
    Joseph    [(1880, [0.022331]), (1881, [0.02267...
    Nancy     [(1880, [0.004211]), (1881, [0.004339]), (1882...
    dtype: object

This problem is a carry over from another post: [plotting in python with congruent x-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612175/plotting-in-python-with-congruent-x-values)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

Comment: @Jonrsharpe : I am sorry I just was trying to make the problem as simple as I could but I am obviously just making i more difficult. Thank you for your patcients everyone on here has been so great Thanks for helping me get my sorry code up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to *sum* all numbers associated to a year?

```
arr = [ (1880, [ 0.25, 0.5 ]), (1881, [ 0.125, 0.25 ]), (1882, [ 0.5, 0.75 ]) ]

for i, (year, numbers) in enumerate(arr):
    arr[i][1][:] = [ sum(numbers) ]
print arr
```

This will print:

```
[(1880, [0.75]), (1881, [0.375]), (1882, [1.25])]
```

Comment: Thanks you. how would I set arr = Joseph Group?

Comment: I don't understand that question, please explain what you mean.  Taken literally, I could answer:  Well, to do that assignment, just write `arr = [(1880, [0.022331]), (1881, [0.02267...` which probably wasn't what you meant.

Comment: The array is an output that should add the two numbers in the list of the two possible values. The 1880 is the year and the number(s) that it is a tuple with are the proportion for the male and female gender. the idea is to find all the people with the name regardless of gender for a given year.

Answer (score 1):

```
end_list = []
for year, nums in items:
    for num in nums:
        end_list.append((year, [num]))
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done.